# Update text in textboxes from selected item in listbox. Listbox works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, textbox, listbox

I built a WinForm app that works fine with SQL database stored online. I am now trying to move to asp.net app. After learning everything I needed to build the WinForm app I am frustrated over new learning curve!

This is a basic app that has a listbox with all people in the database. The listbox display the combined NameLast + ‘, ‘ + NameFirst as NameFull showing something like “Smith, John”. When the user selects a person the textboxes should display the related information. Once I get started it should be easy however… How do I build a OnSelectedChanged type command to fill the textboxes. In this example I would have four (4) textboxes: NameFirstTxt, NameMiddleTxt, NameLastTxt and RecordIDTxt.

I have attached code from the WinForm app used during the selected index change event.
Any advice and comments (good or bad) would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

```
    private void peopleDetailsDirectoryLbx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        peopleDirectoryGbx.Text = "People Records : " + peopleDetailsDirectoryLbx.Items.Count.ToString();
        DataRowView PeopleRow = peopleDetailsDirectoryLbx.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if (PeopleRow != null && PeopleRow.Row != null && PeopleRow.Row.ItemArray != null)
        {
            DataRow row = PeopleRow.Row;
            if (row.ItemArray.Count() > 0)
                try
                {
                    peopleDetailsIDTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(row["ID"]).ToString();

                    try
                    {
                        peopleDetailsPhotoImg.Load(@"http://www.officertech.com/PeoplePhotoBase/" + peopleDetailsIDTxt.Text + ".jpg");
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        peopleDetailsPhotoImg.Load(@"http://www.officertech.com/PeoplePhotoBase/NoPhoto.jpg");
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["Active"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleDetailsActiveChk.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleDetailsActiveChk.Checked = false;
                    }
                    peopleDetailsNameFirstTxt.Text = (row["NameFirst"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsNameMiddleTxt.Text = (row["NameMiddle"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsNameLastTxt.Text = (row["NameLast"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsNameAka1Txt.Text = (row["NameAKA1"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsNameAka2Txt.Text = (row["NameAKA2"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsDobTxt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DOB"]).ToShortDateString();
                    peopleDetailsRaceCbx.Text = (row["Race"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsGenderCbx.Text = (row["Gender"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsAddStreetNumTxt.Text = (row["AddStreetNum"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsStreetNameCbx.Text = (row["AddStreetName"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsAddCityTxt.Text = (row["AddCity"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsAddStateTxt.Text = (row["AddState"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsAddZipTxt.Text = (row["AddZip"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsAddCountyTxt.Text = (row["AddCounty"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsDriverLicenseTxt.Text = (row["DriverLicense"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsDriverLicenseStateTxt.Text = (row["DriverLicenseState"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsSSNTxt.Text = (row["SSN"]).ToString();
                    peopleDetailsTrackingLab.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    if (row["Tracking"].ToString() == "True")
                    {
                        peopleDetailsTrackingYesRad.Checked = true;
                        peopleDetailsTrackingLab.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleDetailsTrackingNoRad.Checked = true;
                        peopleDetailsTrackingLab.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    peopleDetailsPhysIDColorHairCbx.Text = (row["PhysIDColorHair"].ToString());
                    peopleDetailsPhysIDColorEyesCbx.Text = (row["PhysIDColorEyes"].ToString());
                    peopleDetailsPhysIDWeightTxt.Text = (row["PhysIDWeight"].ToString());
                    peopleDetailsPhysIDHeightTxt.Text = (row["PhysIDHeight"].ToString());
                    peopleDetailsPhysIDScarTattTxt.Text = (row["PhysIDScarTatt"].ToString());
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["School"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleDetailsSchoolRad.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleDetailsSchoolRad.Checked = false;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["Work"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleDetailsWorkRad.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleDetailsWorkRad.Checked = false;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciAssault"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIAssaultChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIAssaultChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIAssaultChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIAssaultChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    peopleDetailsSchoolWorkNameTxt.Text = (row["SchoolWorkName"]).ToString();
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciBattery"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIBatteryChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIBatteryChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciBatteryAgg"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryAggChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIBatteryAggChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryAggChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIBatteryAggChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciBatteryDVR"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryDVRChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIBatteryDVRChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryDVRChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIBatteryDVRChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciBatteryLEO"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryLEOChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIBatteryLEOChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIBatteryLEOChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIBatteryLEOChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciBurglary"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIBurglaryChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIBurglaryChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIBurglaryChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIBurglaryChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciChildCrimes"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIChildCrimeChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIChildCrimeChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIChildCrimeChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIChildCrimeChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciCrimMisch"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCICrimMischChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCICrimMischChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCICrimMischChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCICrimMischChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciDealStolen"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIDealStolenChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIDealStolenChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIDealStolenChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIDealStolenChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciDisorderly"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIDisorderlyChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIDisorderlyChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIDisorderlyChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIDisorderlyChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciDrugs"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIDrugsChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIDrugsChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIDrugsChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIDrugsChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciDUI"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIDUIChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIDUIChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIDUIChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIDUIChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciDWLSR"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIDWLSRChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIDWLSRChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIDWLSRChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIDWLSRChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciFraud"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIFraudChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIFraudChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIFraudChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIFraudChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciHomicide"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIHomicideChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIHomicideChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIHomicideChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIHomicideChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciLewdLasciv"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCILewdLascivChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCILewdLascivChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCILewdLascivChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCILewdLascivChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciMental"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIMentalChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIMentalChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIMentalChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIMentalChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    peopleCIProbationLab.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    if (row["ciProbation"].ToString() == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIProbationYesRad.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIProbationLab.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIProbationNoRad.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIProbationLab.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciResisting"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIResistingChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIResistingChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIResistingChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIResistingChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciRobbery"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIRobberyChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIRobberyChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIRobberyChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIRobberyChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciSexCrime"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCISexCrimeChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCISexCrimeChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCISexCrimeChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCISexCrimeChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciShoplift"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIShopLiftChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIShopLiftChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIShopLiftChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIShopLiftChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciTheft"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCITheftChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCITheftChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCITheftChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCITheftChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciTraffic"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCITrafficChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCITrafficChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCITrafficChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCITrafficChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciTrespass"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCITrespassChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCITrespassChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCITrespassChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCITrespassChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciWarrants"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIWarrantsChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIWarrantsChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIWarrantsChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIWarrantsChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    if (Convert.ToString(row["ciWeapons"].ToString()) == "True")
                    {
                        peopleCIWeaponsChk.Checked = true;
                        peopleCIWeaponsChk.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        peopleCIWeaponsChk.Checked = false;
                        peopleCIWeaponsChk.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    //////
                    CalcAge_People();
                    //arrestFieldsFill();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Problem Locating Person Information" + ex, "CARDS 2012 | Message Center", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it work or the goal is to port it over to asp.net?

Comment: I suspect when you migrated the code from WinForm to ASP.NET, you simply copy code and fix compile errors. Instead, the best way is to use the ASP.NET Studio to create the GUI, and populate the code for the back end. The Web ASP.NET GUI is much different in the Web world.  For example, the .NET Studio needs the XML file in form of *.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **AutoPostback** property of ListBox is set to true.

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>1st Person</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2nd Person</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3rd person</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    FIRST NAME:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    LASTNAME:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    EMAIL:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected == true)
                {
                    // what ever you want to assign to TextBox 
                    this.TextBox1.Text = li.Text + "First Name"; // (row["NameFirst"]).ToString();
                    this.TextBox2.Text = li.Text + "Last Name";
                    this.TextBox3.Text = li.Text + "Email";
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: MMK, Thanks and I am close. I am filling the listbox with 'Select *, NameLast + ", " + NameFirst AS NameFull Order By NameFull' which gives me list I need such as Adams, Mark/ Adams, Steve/ Adams, William. What I need is the name textboxes to show the NameFirst, NameMiddle, NameLast fields which are in the SQL database. How do I reference the row selected so that I can pull the fields from the record? Thanks.

Comment: Like but inside foreach loop like (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected == true)
                {// excute sql query to fetch the details  on the bases of selected name from list box you can use Data Reader
 peopleDetailsNameFirstTxt.Text =  reader["Whatever Column"].ToString()               }}